# How can I do offline reasoning with Pellet?

Tags: semantic-web, owl, rdfs, pellet, semweb

I have an OWL ontology and I am using Pellet to do reasoning over it. Like most ontologies it starts by including various standard ontologies:

```
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#">
```

I know that some reasoners have these standard ontologies 'built-in', but Pellet doesn't. Is there any way I can continue to use Pellet when I am offline & can't access them? (Or if their URL goes offline, like dublincore.org did last week for routine maintenance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pellet recognizes all of these namespaces when loading and should not attempt to dereference the URIs.  If it does, it suggests the application using Pellet is doing something incorrectly.

You may find more help on [the pellet-users mailing list](http://lists.owldl.com/mailman/listinfo/pellet-users/).

Answer (score 3):

A generalized solution to this problem -- access to ontologies w/out public Web access -- is described in [Local Ontology Repositories with Pellet](http://clarkparsia.com/weblog/2009/03/16/local-ontology-repositories-with-pellet/). Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

Make local copies of the four files and replace the remote URLs with local URIs (i.e. file://... or serve them from your own box:  http://localhost...).

Comment: Would thi work without modifying the local files... given that the namespace is being used for ontology retrieval, I don't think this would work.

Comment: Would modifying URLs in the local copies be sufficient to allow this to work? 
And, of course, I'd need to take copies of any ontologies imported by the local ontologies....